# Replace all strings matching a search criterion with another string in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have data that looks like this:

```
                  sources
 1:           Jana’s iPhone
 2:     Richard's iPhone 6
 3:               Denise's
 4:           Sara’s iPhone
 5:     Jeff’s Apple Watch
 6:    BLAIR’s Apple Watch
 7:      Sunshine's iPhone
 8:         Brian's iPhone
 9: Jonathan’s Apple Watch
10: patricia’s Apple Watch
```

I'm trying to replace any string that contains `iPhone` just say `iPhone`. How can I do this?

I tried the following on a data table `sources` that contains a column also called `sources`:

```
sources[length(grep("iPhone", sources)) > 0, sources:= "iPhone"]
```

But this converts all rows to "iPhone" even if the row did not originally contain a string with "iPhone". I am guessing this is because grep or length is not vectorized, so I end up selecting all rows. So then my question becomes how can I identify the rows that contain a substring?

Answer (score 5):

Use `grepl` instead:

```
sources[grepl("iPhone", sources), sources:= "iPhone"]
```

Comment: And `fixed = TRUE` for efficiency